Am I being over anxious in thinking?
I have worked at my current workplace for 3 years. I enjoy my work.
The company has two main departments, as well as accounts department and HR department.
When I first started the job, the job was general administrator, so I did a bit of everything and didn’t work for a particular department (the company is all in the same building). Then after six months I was approached by one of the departments' supervisors, asking if I would like to do the role of project coordinator working within one of the main departments.
I did this role for around a year. My appraisal was then scheduled, to which I mentioned that I would like the opportunity to become office manager, which would mean I worked between the two main departments. My boss thought it a good idea and said that I'm a good worker, always got work done on time, never had any complaints etc about me, and not long after I was offered the position. I think I did a good job with it.
During this time my old supervisor and boss had asked me to help out a little bit, which i was happy to do. This was doing some filing once a day, which took about 10 minutes to do, and also scanning of previous contract files. Yes, this task will take time, but not so that I couldn't do my main job duties.
A few weeks ago, out of the blue, my boss came to me and in passing said, as I am doing more work for the department that I use to work in, that my boss wanted to make one of my colleagues office manager. My colleague works for the other main department to me.
After this I was very taken aback, and now I am over-thinking things and becoming anxious in the fact that my boss told me in such a casual way. Also it wasn't mentioned what my job role will now be. This has now made me think things such as, does this mean I will be dismissed or laid off… all the bad things, worst case scenario.
My boss is currently on holiday for a week, which doesn't do anything for me, except leave me with anxiousness. What do you make of and think of the situation – am  I anxiously overthinking this?

TL;DR. Wall of text is hard to read. And all the details are probably irrelevant. I'll submit an edit to fix the first, at least

Given what you have said, yes, you are overthinking this. You have questions that we can't give you the answers to; you need to ask your management what their plans are.
Nothing is likely to happen before your manager returns from holiday. So I'd file it under "that's interesting" and wait for the other shoe to drop, if it ever does.
If you can't calm yourself enough to wait, ask your manager's manager. They probably know what's going on, if anything is going on.

Thank you for your answer,however I cannot ask my managers manager,due to my boss being the CEO of the company.

In that case, all you can really do is continue doing your job and ask when he comes back. Or ask other top brass whether he discussed it with them, but it sounds like he may not have. Your assigned tasks haven't changed yet, and might not ... Or might change for the better. All you know is that you don't know;. That may be reason to be cautious and perhaps to be prepared for whatever change occurs, but I don't think it's reason to panic.

Bosses aren't mind readers (although that would be a useful skill to have).
You need to talk to your boss (when they are back) and tell them what you want:
"Hey boss, I really want to try the office manager position. The work I'm currently doing for department ABC is less than 20 minutes a day and I don't think it would interfere with the new role. What do you think? What other concerns do you have?"

am I anxiously overthinking this

Yes. Instead of worrying focus on the future discussion with your boss. Write down what you want to say and start practicing it. Think about potential replies from your boss and plan ahead how you can address and react to them. This will give you confidence for the upcoming meeting and and hopefully makes you a lot less anxious.
